# Splitting zAware polyline by points using ArcObjects with C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geometry, line, splitting

I'm trying to split a polyline by the boundaries of a polygon using IPolyCurve2.SplitAtPoints using C#.
The polyline I'm trying to split is zAware and holds elevation values at a regular interval.
After splitting the polyline I would obviously like to get the different parts and save them as new features in my feature class, then deleting the original one.
The problem is that when I try to set feature.shape to the geometry in my geometry collection made up of all the polyline parts, I get the error message that the geometry has no Z values.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? I've looked around in the forum but all I found was code that doesn't deal with polylines that hold Z values.

Here is the code I'm using, passing in the original polyline, the point collection that holds all the intersection points with the polygon and the original feature class I create new features in.

```
public void SplitPolylineFeature(IFeature pPolylineFeature, IPointCollection pSplitPointCollection, IFeatureClass pFeatureClass)
    {
        //split the feature, each split makes a new part
        IEnumVertex pEnumVertex = pSplitPointCollection.EnumVertices;
        IPolycurve2 pPolyCurve = pPolylineFeature.Shape as IPolycurve2;
        IEnumSplitPoint pEnumSplitPoint = pPolyCurve.SplitAtPoints(pEnumVertex, true, true, -1);
        object Missing = Type.Missing;

        if(pEnumSplitPoint.SplitHappened)
        {
            //new geocoll for polycurve
            IGeometryCollection pGeometryCollection = pPolyCurve as IGeometryCollection;

            //loop through the parts of the split polyline
            for(int intPartCount = 0; intPartCount < pGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; intPartCount++)
            {
                IGeometryCollection pLineGeoColl = new PolylineClass();
                IGeometry pGeometry = pGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(intPartCount);
                //IZAware zAware1 = (IZAware)pGeometry;
                //zAware1.ZAware = true;

                pLineGeoColl.AddGeometry(pGeometry, ref Missing, ref Missing);

                IFeature pFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature();

                pFeature.Shape = pLineGeoColl as IGeometry;  //code crashes here: Geometry has no Z values
                pFeature.Store();

            }
        }
        pPolylineFeature.Delete();
    }
```

Comment: At a minimum I think you need to set your pLineGeoColl to be ZAware. Probably give it a spatial reference as well. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: This old ESRI forum post has a slightly different approach but worth a look: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=82601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
public void SplitPolylineFeature(IFeature pPolylineFeature, IPointCollection pSplitPointCollection, IFeatureClass pFeatureClass)
{
    //split the feature, each split makes a new part
    IEnumVertex pEnumVertex = pSplitPointCollection.EnumVertices;
    IPolycurve2 pPolyCurve = pPolylineFeature.Shape as IPolycurve2;
    IEnumSplitPoint pEnumSplitPoint = pPolyCurve.SplitAtPoints(pEnumVertex, true, true, -1);
    object Missing = Type.Missing;

    if(pEnumSplitPoint.SplitHappened)
    {
        //new geocoll for polycurve
        IGeometryCollection pGeometryCollection = pPolyCurve as IGeometryCollection;

        //loop through the parts of the split polyline
        for(int intPartCount = 0; intPartCount < pGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; intPartCount++)
        {
            IGeometryCollection pLineGeoColl = new PolylineClass();
            IZAware zAware1 = (IZAware)pLineGeoColl;
            zAware1.ZAware = true;

            IGeometry pGeometry = pGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(intPartCount);

            pLineGeoColl.AddGeometry(pGeometry, ref Missing, ref Missing);

            IFeature pFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature();

            pFeature.Shape = pLineGeoColl as IGeometry;
            pFeature.Store();
        }
    }
    pPolylineFeature.Delete();
}
```

All I did was make `pLineGeoColl` ZAware.