# How to split geometry at points using Arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, splitting

I am attempting to split the geometry of a line feature for further manipulation, without modifying the feature itself.  I am using an IPointCollection, consisting of points that intersect the line, to split the line, where I can find the midpoint of these line segments.  My code:

```
IFeature m_feature = some polyline feature;
IFeatureClass pointFeatureClass = some point feature class;

// storage for point geometry
IGeometry multipoint = new Multipoint() as IGeometry;
multipoint.SpatialReference = m_feature.Shape.SpatialReference;
IPointCollection intersectingPoints = (IPointCollection)multipoint;

// get intersecting points
sFilter.Geometry = (IGeometry)m_feature.Shape;
sFilter.GeometryField = pointFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
sFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;

IFeatureCursor pCursor = pointFeatureClass.Search(sFilter, false);
IFeature thisFeature;
object Missing = Type.Missing;
while ((thisFeature = pCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
{
    IPoint pnt = thisFeature.Shape as IPoint;
    pnt.SpatialReference = thisFeature.Shape.SpatialReference;
    intersectingPoints.AddPoint(pnt, ref Missing, ref Missing);
}

MessageBox.Show(intersectingPoints.PointCount.ToString()); // returns correct number (i.e. greater than 1)

// split m_feature polyline at intersecting points into individual polyline objects
IPolycurve2 polyCurve = (IPolycurve2)m_feature.Shape;
IEnumVertex splitPoints = intersectingPoints.EnumVertices;
IEnumSplitPoint enumSplitPoint = polyCurve.SplitAtPoints(splitPoints, true, true, -1);

// check if split occurred
if (enumSplitPoint.SplitHappened)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Split Happened") // always shows as split
}

// new geoCol for polycurve
IGeometryCollection geoColl = (IGeometryCollection)polyCurve;
MessageBox.Show(geoColl.GeometryCount.ToString()); // prints 1 as if split didn't occur
```

Referencing [Splitting zAware polyline by points using ArcObjects with C#?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54267) and [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51288).

What am I doing that might be causing the polycurve object to not be split?  Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: You're adding the points to intersectingVOPs but splitting using points in intersectingPoints. You shouldn't need to set pnt.SpatialReference = thisFeature.Shape.SpatialReference; but that's neither here nor there.. finding points (assuming sFilter is ISpatialFilter) with a line is bound to be hit and miss, try buffering by a little bit. Is this splitting any lines? Is your m_feature returned from a non-recycling cursor? Are the spatial references the same? i.e. you might need to pnt.Project(m_feature.Shape.SpatialReference) to ensure they're compatible.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks for taking the blinders off of me.  See my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thinking out aloud. So all the action occurs here:

```
IEnumSplitPoint enumSplitPoint = polyCurve.SplitAtPoints(splitPoints, true, true, -1)
```

- Your cut off distance is -1. Not sure that should be negative? The
  [API help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IPolycurve2_SplitAtPoints.htm) for this method on this interface does not say anything
  about negative numbers, may be try a positive value?
- You have set the parameter *createParts* to TRUE. May be your count which is returning 1 is returning a count of 1 polyline but its actually a multi-part shape, each part being the line segment you wanted?

Comment: In the examples I linked in my question, I had seen the cutoffdistance = -1.  I had assumed that this would not grab any points off of the line.  I had tried 0.0, which resulted in the enumSplitPoint.SplitHappened = False, so i had wrongly assumed that the -1 was working.  Being in a GCS, i was hesitant to use any large positive cutoffdistance, but as MichaelMiles-Stimson pointed out, since i used a spatial query to build my pointcollection, the intersecting points will be hit or miss.  However, a cutOffDistance of 0.1 did the trick.  Thanks